# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationExceptionnnn

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here is a code:

```
@Override
public Article insert(Article article,String sql) {

    try {
        pr = super.get(sql);
        pr.setInt(1, article.getId());
        pr.setString(2, article.getName());
        pr.setString(3, article.getDescription());
        pr.setString(4, article.getAuthor());
        pr.setString(5, article.getPicture_url());
        pr.setDouble(6, article.getPrice());
        pr.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        DbHandler.showErrorMessage(e);
    }

    return article;
}
```

@XmlRootElement
public class Article {

```
private String name;
private String description;
private String picture_url;
private String author;
private int id;
private double price;

public Article() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Article(String name, String description, String picture_url, String author, int id, double price) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.picture_url = picture_url;
    this.author = author;
    this.id = id;
    this.price = price;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getPicture_url() {
    return picture_url;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
```

}

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Article insert(Article article) {
    return repo.insert(article, "insert into book values (?, ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)");
}
```

When i try to insert the Article in database with POST method every time i have MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException and the message is 'name can not be null'? Can someone help me what is the problem here?

And also i have database table with two primary keys with id and name

This is a screenshot in postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfAPq.png)

Comment: Could you add the table description?

Comment: Start by specifying the column names i  yoru SQL instead of hoping you insert the values in the right order. Then check that the name od the article you insert isn't null.

Comment: Your article class is an un mutable I suggest you to add assertion to avoid null value for your keys this will help you to debug

Comment: Ok thanks for advices. But also i want to mention it that i everything already test in JUnit and everything works fine. But the problem is only when i want to insert article throw the POST metohd.

Comment: Joakim Danieslon here is table description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2CUl.png